# Module not found: Can't resolve '@/amplifyconfiguration.json'

Tags: aws-amplify

After setting up AWS Amplify (Gen2) project for the first time;
encountered the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@/amplifyconfiguration.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is the missing `amplifyconfiguration.json`

To generate it; you'd need to run:

`npx amplify sandbox`

p.s. probably some other commands may generate it as well; e.g. git push; basically that file gets generated for the deployment; see also: https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/reference/amplifyconfiguration/